# Create trigger error

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers

I am trying to create trigger and it gives me `Error(27,45): PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'OLD.RECEIVED_COST'` error. I have same column name in the `source` and `target`.

```
create or replace TRIGGER test
AFTER DELETE
ON source
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO target(match_id, ktr_num, order_no, matched_keytrol_amt, RECEIVED_COST)
  VALUES (:OLD.match_id, :OLD.ktr_num, :OLD.order_no, :OLD.MATCHED_KEYTROL_AMT, :OLD.RECEIVED_COST);
END;
```

The table source structure is

```
MATCH_ID    NUMBER(10,0)    
KTR_NUM NUMBER(10,0)    
ORDER_NO    NUMBER(12,0)
MATCHED_KEYTROL_AMT NUMBER(20,4)    
RECEIVED_COST   NUMBER(20,4)
```

Target table structure is

```
MATCH_ID    NUMBER(10,0)
KTR_NUM NUMBER(10,0)
ORDER_NO    NUMBER(12,0)
MATCHED_KEYTROL_AMT NUMBER(20,4)
RECEIVED_COST   NUMBER(20,4)
SESSION_ID  NUMBER
```

Comment: are you sure about the spelling of the received_cost column in the source table?  Using your scripts above I've managed to compile that trigger

Comment: My bad. in the source table the column name is diff than what i have mentioned in the trigger.  Thanks

Comment: no problem - we've all made the same mistake in the past